# vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, bios

I am having problems running VirtualBox on my Ubuntu laptop. My laptop is dual boot, and running (Windows 10 - I think, haven't used it in years), as well as Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

**I have secure boot enabled on the BIOS settings of my laptop.**

I am aware that there are similar questions posted on here, specifically these two:

- [Failed installation of Virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852590/failed-installation-of-virtualbox-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [VirtualBox Installation gives message “modprobe vboxdrv” failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802668/virtualbox-installation-gives-message-modprobe-vboxdrv-failed)

I have followed all of the instructions given in the answers sections for those two questions - yet, the problem remains unresolved.

Here is the console output, when I attempt to run virtualbox:

```
me@YOURBOX:~$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-47-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

here is the console output when I run`/sbin/vboxconfig` as suggested:

```
me@YOURBOX:~$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig  
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Here is the tail end of the output of `dmesg`:

```
[   44.319682] audit: type=1400 audit(1491313982.374:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=705 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.041433] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   59.682936] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   59.697820] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   59.702008] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f0: link is not ready
[   60.267000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f0: link is not ready
[   62.473044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   70.681706] audit_printk_skb: 60 callbacks suppressed
[   70.681709] audit: type=1400 audit(1491314008.734:32): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=2009 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   70.850936] aufs 4.x-rcN-20160111
[   75.407218] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   75.408555] Bridge firewalling registered
[   75.427172] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   75.848416] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   76.703232] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   77.060003] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[   80.101042] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1402]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[  113.895236] wlp3s0: authenticate with 84:16:f9:77:e1:54
[  113.910483] wlp3s0: send auth to 84:16:f9:77:e1:54 (try 1/3)
[  113.912712] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  113.915101] wlp3s0: associate with 84:16:f9:77:e1:54 (try 1/3)
[  113.919397] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 84:16:f9:77:e1:54 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[  113.919516] wlp3s0: associated
[  113.919559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

Now, I'm not going to lie - I have **absolutely no idea** what dmesg just spewed out - and as far as I can tell, there are no error messages in the log output - which makes the situation even more infuriating.

**Has anyone ever installed VirtualBox 5.x on a laptop running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS - but with secure boot enabled on BIOS** ? - if yes, what is the solution. ???!

Lots of people have this problem - even going a few years back. it is very strange that no one seems to have a solution for it - ???

Comment: *"I have secure boot enabled on the BIOS settings of my laptop."* - That may be part of your problem. I remember a while back hearing that secure boot broke VBox.

Comment: Another similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Answer (score 93, accepted):

> ## VirtualBox + Secure Boot + Ubuntu = fail
>
> The problem is the requirement that all kernel modules must be signed
>   by a key trusted by the UEFI system, otherwise loading will fail.
>   Ubuntu does not sign the third party vbox* kernel modules, but rather
>   gives the user the option to disable Secure Boot upon installation of
>   the virtualbox package. I could do that, but then I would see an
>   annoying “Booting in insecure mode” message every time the machine
>   starts, and also the dual boot Windows 10 installation I have would
>   not function.
>
> *Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Latitude E7440 with BIOS A18, and with a dual boot Windows 10 installation.*
>
> Credit goes to the primary source of information I used to resolve
>   this problem, which applies specifically to Fedora/Redhat:
>   http://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/
>
> And a relevant Ask Ubuntu question:
>   [Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur)
>
> ## Steps to make it work, specifically for Ubuntu/Debian
>
> 1. Install the virtualbox package. If the installation detects that Secure Boot is enabled, you will be presented with the issue at hand
>      and given the option to disable Secure Boot. Choose “No”.
> 2. Create a personal public/private RSA key pair which will be used to sign kernel modules. I chose to use the root account and the directory
>      /root/module-signing/ to store all things related to signing kernel
>      modules.
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo -i
>    # mkdir /root/module-signing
>    # cd /root/module-signing
>    # openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=YOUR_NAME/"
>    [...]
>    # chmod 600 MOK.priv
>    ```
> 3. Use the MOK (“Machine Owner Key”) utility to import the public key so that it can be trusted by the system. This is a two step process
>      where the key is first imported, and then later must be enrolled when
>      the machine is booted the next time. A simple password is good enough,
>      as it is only for temporary use.
>
>    ```
>    # mokutil --import /root/module-signing/MOK.der
>    input password:
>    input password again:
>    ```
> 4. Reboot the machine. When the bootloader starts, the MOK manager EFI utility should automatically start. It will ask for parts of the
>      password supplied in step 3. Choose to “Enroll MOK”, then you should
>      see the key imported in step 3. Complete the enrollment steps, then
>      continue with the boot. The Linux kernel will log the keys that are
>      loaded, and you should be able to see your own key with the command:
>      `dmesg|grep 'EFI: Loaded cert'`
> 5. Using a signing utility shippped with the kernel build files, sign all the VirtualBox modules using the private MOK key generated in step 2.
>      I put this in a small script `/root/module-signing/sign-vbox-modules`, so it can be easily run when new kernels are installed as part of regular updates:
>
>    ```
>    #!/bin/bash
>
>    for modfile in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/*.ko; do
>      echo "Signing $modfile"
>      /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 \
>                                    /root/module-signing/MOK.priv \
>                                    /root/module-signing/MOK.der "$modfile"
>    done
>    ```
>
>    And then:
>
>    ```
>    # chmod 700 /root/module-signing/sign-vbox-modules
>    ```
> 6. Run the script from step 5 as root. You will need to run the signing script every time a new kernel update is installed, since this
>      will cause a rebuild of the third party VirtualBox modules. Use the
>      script only after the new kernel has been booted, since it relies on
>      `modinfo -n` and `uname -r` to tell which kernel version to sign for.
> 7. Load vboxdrv module and fire up VirtualBox:
>
>    ```
>    # modprobe vboxdrv
>    ```
>
> The procedure can also be used to sign other third party kernel
>   modules, like the nvidia graphics drivers, if so is required. (I have
>   not tested that myself.)

**Note:** The above answer was wholly sourced from Øyvind Stegard's blog post, [VirtualBox + Secure Boot + Ubuntu = fail](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/).

Comment: I get an error: `vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxnetflt failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.` 

dmesg: `[70567.246789] vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores
[70567.267310] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2166734189 Hz
[70567.267315] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.40_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)`

Comment: Great Answer and thanks for the script!  I'd like to add that if **vagrant up still fails on VboxManage hostonlyif create**, then it can be remedied by uninstalling both vagrant and virtualbox, then reinstalling. Assuming you've already signed the keys. Cheers!

Comment: Has Ubuntu 18 fixed this, or will it never be fixed for security reasons?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I have no idea - I personally hate UEFI and always install in MBR mode......

Comment: Note about 18.04+: the suggested grep should read: `dmesg|grep 'EFI:'` in stead of `dmesg|grep 'EFI: Loaded cert'`

Comment: Absolutely don't know and understand what this does, but it worked.

Comment: Just in case some needed: I had this problem w/o UEFI or Secure Mode. In my case, virtualbox-dkms installation on 18.04.x was broken. My fix was: apt purge virtualbox-dkms &&  apt install virtualbox-dkms && modprobe vboxdrv

Comment: if you upgrade virtualbox from 5.2 to 6.0 don't forget complete 6 and 7 steps again.

Comment: Returned to this answer again. I remember about this script on the system and run it in case of the problem with loading of the VM. But I always forget about 7-th step, so I recommend to put the command at the end of the script of the 6-th step. It is definitely a time saver for the next time.

Comment: it works with ubuntu 18 and virtual box 6

Comment: The above solution worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04 with secure boot), however I had difficulties when tried to enroll MOK, it refused the password all the time. 
I've found out
- maximum password lenght is 5 characters
- somebody noticed MOK manager might use azerty keyboard
So I suggest to use "12345" as the password, it worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

The above answer probably works fine, but if you want an easier time for it:

I was able to solve it by

booting into the BIOS and going > advanced (f7) > boot > scroll down to "secure boot" > change "Windows EUFI mode" to "other OS"

My virtualbox works perfectly now.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to do this?

Comment: Due to some power surge or something my BIOS had gotten reset so I needed to do this. Now I don't get the above error.