# Virtualbox with SecureBoot

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I follow this guide to setup virtualbox with secure boot:
https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/

I follow all steps, and when try to run /sbin/vboxconfig I get the following error:

`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.`

Command `modprobe vboxdrv` return:

`sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available`

**UPDATE**

After following the solution in my answer I get this error when try to install a virtual machine:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {xxx-yyy-xxx-yyy-xxx}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

hmmm... seem that issue is caused by this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl

So I can't allocate more than 3GB?`

**UPDATE Important step that I missed:**

Enable Virtualization in BIOS!

Comment: Check if the following links help [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900118/vboxdrv-sh-failed-modprobe-vboxdrv-failed-please-use-dmesg-to-find-out-why), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox)

Comment: I read all this and others questions, however they are pretty similar to tutorial that I linked, and which is most recent. I found a solution, but can't understand why it work... I will post in answer so you maybe can help me understand. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution but I am not sure why it work.

In the tutorial here: https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/
there is script for sign and load module and should be run after each kernel compile.

However, I found another one, this:
https://github.com/Majal/maj-scripts/blob/master/vboxsign

Which do the work and I can run virtualbox successfully.

```

```
bash vboxsign
vboxdrv: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxdrv successfully loaded
vboxnetflt: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxnetflt successfully loaded
vboxnetadp: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxnetadp successfully loaded
vboxpci: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxpci successfully loaded
```

```

Second run return:

```

```
bash vboxsign
Module vboxdrv is already signed. Skipping.
vboxdrv: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxdrv successfully loaded
Module vboxnetflt is already signed. Skipping.
vboxnetflt: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxnetflt successfully loaded
Module vboxnetadp is already signed. Skipping.
vboxnetadp: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxnetadp successfully loaded
Module vboxpci is already signed. Skipping.
vboxpci: ..~Module signature ap*
vboxpci successfully loaded
```

```

If I run `/sbin/vboxconfig` after sign the modules then the key seem again lost:

```

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

```

I think that command `/sbin/vboxconfig` should be run again after sign modules, but it seem that this command reset back signing...

So maybe also other script work but I have reset them.

If I just run `virtualbox` there is not anymore message error that modules are not signed and virtualbox run seem normally. Need to test if work fine.

**Important step that I missed:**

Enable Virtualization in BIOS!