# VirtualBox kernel driver installation uses bogus kernel version

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, mate

I meet a problem installing Virtualbox kernel driver on Ubuntu MATE 20.04.

The running kernel is 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64.

No UEFI.

Reinstalling goes like this:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /lib/modules/5.4.73: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /lib/modules/5.4.73: No such file or directory
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

5.4.73 is a bogus kernel version and if /lib/modules/5.4.73 doesn't exist, vboxconfig creates it.

But it obviously lacks its normal content and vboxconfig fails.

Certainly not the duplicate of another question (read twice)

The questions are:

- where does vboxconfig pick that bogus instead of true name?
- what safe action should I take to circumvent that?
  safe means not risking a unbootable system and might be a kernel update installation.

TIA.

Comment: Are your kernel headers installed? Just run `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic` and for the kernel you're currently using `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Also, what does it return when you run: `cat /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/config/kernel.release`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900118/vboxdrv-sh-failed-modprobe-vboxdrv-failed-please-use-dmesg-to-find-out-why)

Comment: @mchid : thanks, my reply is in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment) with outcome at the end
Thanks a lot for your reply mchid.
Yes,  5.4.0.58.61 is installed beside linux-generic 5.4.0.58.61.
I started scanning / for "5.4.73" but before the first hit started displaying your command showed that kernel.release contains that value. Strangely, this mis-installation results from the 20.04 upgrade.
My first idea was to patch kernel.release but I found other files with the bad value and the extent of the damage is unpredictable.
So, the best option is what you said:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-headers-5.4.0-117   linux-headers-5.4.0-117-generic   linux-image-5.4.0-117-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-117-generic   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-117-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
linux-generic   linux-headers-generic   linux-image-generic
```

Unlike a normal reinstall, the old kernel remains unaffected and I'm not sawing the bough I'm sitting on, right?
Thanks again.

**Outcome**

Kernel installation worked as said with sensible messages except

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd:
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
```

and there is no vboxadd-install.log

Virtualbox requested the hosts additions and then ran OK again.
Phew !!!